# How to publish a website/webapp in asp.net and also can we edit a published website without republishing it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fresher to stackoverflow,
please help me to know about the following
How to **publish** a website/webapp in asp.net and also can we edit a published website without republishing it...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Solution Explorer on vs.Right click your website click publish website.create a new profile by clicking on drop down list and edit confg as your like .